# MVC datetime model bind fail for spanish culture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

On a MVC project I'm having problems with spanish dates of the format: `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm` that translate to: `14 feb. 2018 10:56`

on web.config I have define culture as:

```
<globalization culture="es-CR" uiCulture="es"/>
```

My model is able to bind almost any date without problems, but the issue is with March, "Marzo" in Spanish, which is show as `mar.` Any date containing Month March, is not bind properly to model and is how a default date-time: `1 ene. 0001 00:00:00`

I think the problem is that C# is not able to parse the date properly as short month definition for March and short day of week definition for Tuesday on Spanish are equal.

```
March -> Marzo -> mar.
Tuesday -> Martes -> mar
```

Any workaround for it?

If none, any guide so I can write my own datetime parse binding method. Only as a last resource option.

NOTE: same behavior with any Spanish culture, `es` `es-MX` `es-US` etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method to parse the input into a `DateTime` value using an English `CultureInfo`. Then you can use the `DateTime.ToString` method with a Spanish `CultureInfo` to convert the `DateTime` value to a string.

```
var input = "Tuesday, July 26, 2011";
var format = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));

var result = dt.ToString(format, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
// result == "martes, julio 26, 2011"
```

Consider that a Spanish user might prefer the Spanish standard format over your custom format though:

```
var result = dt.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
// result == "martes, 26 de julio de 2011"
```

Comment: That in fact works, but how can use ParseExact Method on model binding? When users submit from View, on controller DateTime was not bind, then cannot use ParseExact there.

Comment: no idea regarding that but you may take date input in english.